# OS Not Booting Up

Tags: boot, upgrade, boot-repair, partial-upgrade

For a while, my OS hasn't been able to install updates. I ran sudo apt autoremove and a partial upgrade when prompted by the installer. Seemed to go okay. I'm now upgraded to 22.04.

I reboot and the OS won't load. I just get this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhKhQ.jpg)

I've run apt upgrade, autoremove, and full-upgrade from commands. apt update gets me this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3l3Z.jpg)

I can get into recovery mode. Still no luck getting my OS to start. Help?

Comment: Your output strongly suggests a possible kernel bug [Debian: #1003965](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1003965) and a possible network problem. Boot into GRUB and try an older kernel.

Comment: Only kernel I have to pick from is the current one. There anything else I can do?

Comment: I removed it earlier. My OS was refusing to update because of insufficient space on the partition. Regretting that now.

Comment: A "partial upgrade" is generally bad news too. You seems to have a lot of problems (partitioning, partial upgrade, possible kernel bug) that suggest an afternoon doing a backup, re-partition, and reinstall might be time wisely invested.

Comment: Before just removing stuff you might have tried to find out why the partition was reporting full or nearly full. The real reason this all started.